# Field to connect between Child BC and Parent BC

Tags: crm, siebel

this is a question related to Siebel

I am trying to query a field in Parent BC from a Child BC. The thing is, I am not sure which field in the child BC is connected to the parent BC. I have checked the Link between these BC, there is no value in source field and destination field. However, there is an intertable and there are values in the inter child and parent column.

Do I need to use the value there as the connection ? If no, where else should I check for the connected field ?

Thank you.

Comment: If source/destination field is empty, it means that by default field Id is used. Also, you are saying that intertable property has value, that means that relation between BCs is many-to-many. And since it's a M:M relation you cannot simply expose parent fields on the child BC (or vice versa). It can be achieved either using multi-value field or using calculated field with ParentFieldValue function, depending on your requirments.

Comment: Hai Eugene, thank you for your reply. I have managed to find the answer, you can go to 'Drilldown Object' and check the source field(child BC) and the destination field (parent BC).

Answer (score 0):

If inter-table link is being used then that means it is a M:M relationship. One trick is to create a new BusComp based on the inter-table. You can then use the identifier from Child BusComp and query in the inter-table BusComp to get the record. That record will have the identifier of Parent BusComp as well.

This way you have a method to traverse from Child BusComp record to Parent BusComp record.